# Printing Using Java Desktop application

Tags: java, printing

Using desktop application, can I know if there is printer connected to the machine?

I want to identify if the printer is connected,and if not send alert to the user

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387938/how-to-check-printer-is-connected-or-not-to-your-pc-by-java?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Java Print Service API from jdk1.5+